# Showing value from array of data in React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I fetched this data from my API. How can I show the value of the name property in a text input?

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "userid": "",
        "is_admin": "1",
        "name": "Anshul Gupta",
        "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
        "company": "Kissui Metaliks and Steels Pvt. Ltd.",
        "jobtitle": "Director",
        "address": "366 and 368, MIE Part A, Bahadurgarh,Haryana,IndiaBahadurgarh, Haryana",
        "cityid": "haryana",
        "stateid": "Abohar",
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? yourArray[0]['name'] returns the name !

Comment: fetched this data from api want to render its value like name,email etc on textinput

Comment: Please share the input area code!

Comment: constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     
      dataSource:[],
    }
   
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    try {
       
       
        AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then(async (user)=>{
        
          
            const response = await fetch('https://myAPi=' + userData.id );
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            
   
            
            this.setState({
               
                dataSource: responseJson,
              
            })
            
        })
        
      }
     
  }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess this is what you are looking for :

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

        export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { dataSource:[]}
          }

          async componentDidMount(){
            try {
              AsyncStorage.getItem("user")
                .then(async (user)=>{
                  const response = await fetch('myAPi=' + userData.id );
                  const responseJson = await response.json();
                  this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson})
                })
            }
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>{this.state.dataSource[0]['name']}</Text>
                <TextInput
                  style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }} 
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                  value={this.state.dataSource[0]['name']}
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }} 
                  onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
                  value={this.state.dataSource[0]['email']}
                />
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: yes but this doesnt show name.throw error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource[0]['name']')

Comment: It may be is because of your data! look at this : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Comment: So it's the componentdidmount problem. What is inside datasource after setState ?

Comment: datasource Array [
  Object {
  
    "id": "1",
    "is_admin": "1",
    "is_superseller": "0",
    "jobtitle": "Director",
    "lastlogin": "2019-09-30 07:08:57",
    "logincount": "27267",
    "mobile": "9871323193",
    "mobile1": "fdfd",
    "name": "Anshul Gupta",
    "password": "ss1234554321pl",

  },
]

Comment: @DivyaLal  the error may be due to in initial render there is no data available at that point.To avoid error simple solution would be for Text ===><Text>{this.state.dataSource[0] && this.state.dataSource[0]['name']}</Text> and for TextInput ====> value={this.state.dataSource[0] && this.state.dataSource[0]['name']} or value===>{this.state.dataSource[0] ? this.state.dataSource[0]['name']:" "}

Answer (score 0):

hi @DivyaLal its quiet a straight forward answer. all you need to do is use index of particulararray with what ever key u need to display. as you said you need to display values in textinput please check below example

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

    export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
arr= yourArr
}
      }


     render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <TextInput 
    value = {arr[0].name}/> // to display name in textinput

<TextInput 
value={arr[0].email}/> // to dsiplay email
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps.... Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pre-populate the name value from the API in a text input just set the input value with this.setState once the API has fetched the user info.

```
//Your state 

this.state = {
text: ''
}

// Your text input

      <TextInput
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />

// Now when your component loads check if user data is in Async storage otherwise call API.Instead of using await you can use .then and set state after receiving the json.

    AsyncStorage.getItem('user').then(user => {
      fetch('myAPi=' + userData.id)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(responseJson => this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson, text: responseJson.name }));
    });
```

I also recommend **not** using AsyncStorage to store user data as it's completely unencrypted but your call.

Comment: didnt get any value in textinput

Comment: Can you provide your full component code? I think that'll make it easier to debug. Otherwise its easy to make syntax errors while trying many solutions suggested here.